# My userinfo command in discord.js is giving only errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a userinfo command but it aint working.. Only giving errors like:
.join is not a function or member is not defind. My friend also did not get the errors. Anyone who could take a look at it? Thanks!

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    name: 'userinfo',
    description: 'let you see the info about you',
        usage: '[command name]',
    execute(message, args, client) {

        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

        var roles = member.roles.cache.size - 1;
        var roleNames = member.roles.cache.map(r => r).join(" ").replace("@everyone", "");
        if(roles == 0) roleNames = "No roles";

    var embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
    .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
    .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
    .addField("Roles:", message.member.roles.cache.some(roles => `${roles}`).join(', '), true)
    .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
    .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true) 
    .addField("Roles:", member.roles.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', '), true)

    message.channel.send(embed);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this particular error because the member variable is not defined. If you want your code to work, you can add `const member = message.member` to the execute function and it should work

Comment: Than it says message is not defind. Is it not const member = require(message.member)?
Solution: No it das not work. @Caladan

Comment: No, you don't need to use `require(message.member)`, you can just use `const member = message.member`.

Comment: Thanks! 1 problem solved... Now I get the error:
 TypeError: message.member.roles.cache.some(...).join is not a function

Sorry for bothering so much but I really need help at this one ;(

Comment: I think instead of `.some`, you can use `.map`

Comment: Thank you so much, but its not sending the embed rn? Really idk why. Walked by the code 2 times

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: What's your `discord.js` version?

Comment: No errors, Discord.js v13, but I think I got the problem

Answer (score 0):

For the people who want the code: This is it working, only check the avater field!

```
 const discord = require('discord.js');
    const moment = require('moment');
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'userinfo',
    description: 'let you see the info about you',
        usage: '[command name]',
    execute(message, args, client) {

        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const member = message.member

        var roles = member.roles.cache.size - 1;
        var roleNames = member.roles.cache.map(r => r).join(" ").replace("@everyone", "");
        if(roles == 0) roleNames = "No roles";

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
    .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
    .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
    .addField("Roles:", message.member.roles.cache.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', '), true)
    .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
    .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true) 

    message.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
    }
};
```

Comment: To get the avatar as a url, you can just use `message.author.avatarURL()` since it is a function instead of a property